# implement RC5 encryption in java

Tags: java, encryption

I've an assignment currently to implement this RC5 encryption in my java project but I have no much idea how to achieve it.

I tried to create Cipher object as below line and it throw me exception:

```
Cipher desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RC5");
***java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RC5***
```

but other provider like "DES", "RC2" working fine when I create Cipher object,

I'm using jdk6, if it matters

Comment: Are you sure the assignment was to *use* RC5 or to *implement* RC5?

Comment: Sorry, should be.... implement project 'using' RC5 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://bouncycastle.org/ I believe have a RC5 implementation use them as your provider and see if that works.